# Python Adding a Column while using Usecol

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, text, substring

I'm hoping this is rather simple to accomplish but I'm having issues since I'm selecting columns from a text file but also want to add part of my file name as the last, or fourth, column. Naturally, I'm getting an error for the "Expected Axis."

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
files = ('file_20181006.txt')
df = pd.read_table('file_20181006.txt', encoding='cp1252', sep='^', usecols=(0,1,70))
df.columns = ['Row Type','Account Number','Assigned Balance']
print(df[df['Row Type'] == 1])
```

I want to add a column named "Assign Date" which parses my filename grabbing just the "20181006" and that's it.

Comment: I tried to use the assign and insert without any luck. My understanding is I'd need to utilize the output of this df to reference, then use the insert.

Comment: If you tried to use df.assign(colname = '2018-01-01'), this will  not work in your case because your column name has a space "Assign Date".  If it didn't include a space nor special characters `df.assign` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
 df['Assign Date'] = files[-12:-4]
```

Or if you want datetime dtype:

```
df['Assign Date'] = pd.to_datetime(files[-12:-4])
```

Comment: @OmkarSabade He doesn't have enough reputation to upvote yet.  Thanks!

Comment: Done. Thanks again Scott.